# Is it illegal to share my medical bill online?

Tags: united-states, medical, health

Is it illegal to share my medical bill online?

I'm asking because I want to post it to complain about it, but I'm always scared I may get in trouble with some law I don't know about. Like defamation or something like that.

Comment: A bigger concern as far as defamation would probably be whatever commentary you might post together with the bill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is legal for you to publicly distribute your medical records, and it is legal for you to publicly distribute your bills. Defamation would be a concern only if you make a false statement that does harm to someone. A medical bill is a statement made by someone else (in both senses of "statement").

Comment: Isn’t the medical bill subject to copyright?

Comment: Surely not: it's an automatic printout involving nothing creative, just a list of facts.

Comment: Yes, but most invoices include logos and layout choices (within the limits of being an invoice) which would meet the creativity threshold for copyright. I think the proposed usage is fair use/dealing but copyright should be considered.

Comment: In most European jurisdictions the idea of a creativity threshold would violate the dearly-held principle of artistic freedom; pretty much everything that is not yet subject to copyright will be subject to copyright upon its authoring. I have a vague recollection that international law has recently caught up with AI-generated "copyright blankets"; I'm pretty sure an invoice would not overcome the bars set there for using a machine to create work of art. I feel like a patient's interest outweighs the copyright owner's to block the disclosure by knowingly using logos on an invoice.

Comment: Does that mean if I'm developing a crowd sourcing app that allows people to share their medical prices and what they paid would be okay to do so with no trouble under the law? Basically my premise here is to have some transparency in health care costs.